# Можно ли изменить цвет ввода в input с использованием regExp?

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, replace

```js
let t = document.querySelector('.test');

t.addEventListener('keypress', (e)=>{
    e.target.innerHTML = e.target.value.replace(
         /join/gim,
         (m)=>{
           return "<span style='color: red;'>"+m+"</span>"
         }
    );
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="test">
```

Объясните пожалуйста, как можно реализовать данную затею (т.е. изменение цвета НУЖНЫХ МНЕ слов в `input` или к примеру в `textarea` с помощью регулярных выражений) и почему при проверки данного инпута, и вводе ключевого слово join в коде html присутствует спан, который предназначен для замены цвета, НО замены цвета не происходит, т.е. если проинспектить инпут, с введённым мэтченным словом, то мы увидим, `<span style='color: red;'>join</span>`!

Comment: никак, в input нельзя вставить разметку. Если нужно такое поведение - нужно использовать что-то другое. Например div с атрибутом conteneditable

Comment: Grundy, короче сделать див имитирующий инпут, правильно? я так понял атрибут этот даст возможность в див вставлять текст?

Comment: да. тогда вставлять можно будет непосредственно html и он сразу будет рендерится